# Numerical integration of Schwarzschild geodesic equations

Tags: resource-recommendations, orbital-motion, computational-physics, geodesics

I'm interested in numerically integrating the geodesic equations of motion for a test particle in Schwarzschild geometry. Before I even begin the process I'm quite confused about what the results will be. I'd like to compare the results with a Newtonian orbit.

1. Do I only need to integrate the radial equation of motion?
2. Also what would be the output if one integrated the temporal geodesic equation?
3. Do people have any resources to help me in this quest?

It doesn't seem to be something that is covered much.

Answer (score 2):

The trajectory for a particle with total energy equal to $mc^2$ i.e. a particle that starts at rest at infinity and travels in on a radial trajectory is:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = -\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)\sqrt{\frac{r_s}{r}} $$

For a particle that starts with a Lorentz factor of $\gamma$ rather than stationary this is modified to:

$$ \frac{dr}{dt} = -\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)\sqrt{1 - \frac{1}{\gamma^2}\left(1 - \frac{r_s}{r}\right)} $$

Reproducing these results would be a good test of your algorithm.

Comment: Ahhhh this was a post that I half wrote and then thought I had deleted.... I mean actually integrating them numerically. So when I have my four (or three depending on whether we restrict attention to the equatorial plane) integrals for my four coordinates... What do people do then in terms of numerical analysis?